# Neo4J shortestPath through nodes in index

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, shortest-path, cypher

I'm currently using this Cypher query to find the shortest path between two nodes:

```
START topic=node:cities(name='amsterdam'), top=node:categories(name='world')
MATCH p=shortestPath(topic-[*]->top)
RETURN p
```

However, I need the nodes in the path to have a certain property, or better, to be in the index categories. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is something more intricate, you probably should check out the traversal framework and the implementation of the ShortestPath at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/tree/master/community/graph-algo/src/main/java/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/shortestpath

Answer (score 0):

It may be something like that

`START topic=node:cities(name='amsterdam'), top=node:categories(name='world')
MATCH p=shortestPath(topic-[r]->top)
WHERE HAS(r.PROPERTY)
RETURN p`

where PROPERTY is whatever property you want to specify for limiting the output